# Storing position of tiles in windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, winrt-xaml, tiles

I have an application which has multiple tiles in it. I have implemented following functionality:-

1. You can Drag and Drop the tiles.
2. You can form various groups.
3. Edit the tile.
4. Pin to start.

**The only problem** is that i am not able to store the position of tiles so that it appears at same position  once the user has changed its position by dragging and dropping, once the app is closed and opened again.
Basically I want to achieve the functionality of windows 8 start screen.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: tiles within your app aren't a platform feature, are you using some 3rd party or other offering, such as Telerik? It would depend on whether that component retains those settings, and if they don't, you'd have to own storing that information.

Comment: @JimO'Neil  I'm not using any 3rd party component for creating tiles they are my own objects. I just need to know that how to store the locations of the tiles and how to draw them at their proper positions.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the positions of tile items into an XML file, that can be store in Isolated storage. On loaded you can deserialize the XML file and arrange your items based on the values.

For more information,
http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/07/09/example-metro-app-winrt-serializing-and-deseralizing-objects-to-storagefile-and-localfolder-using-generics-and-asyncawait-threading/

Comment: Thanks for reply! but that part i know ,the real problem is how to draw tiles at their proper coordinates after deserialising it.

Comment: What container you using for adding tiles?